# How to allow a class to accept all derived classes of another class?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, inheritance, state

I am making an enemy script which uses a state machine based on classes, I have made a State class which all the different states are derived from and each of these classes require an EnemyController class for its variables and methods. I have also made 3 different enemy classes which derive from the EnemyController class but these cannot be input into the states. I want to find a way so that I can input these three enemy scripts into the states but they only seem to take the parent EnemyController script.

```
public State(EnemyController enemy)
{
    this.enemy = enemy;
}
```

Each of the states require a parameter of EnemyController but I want it to be able to use either EnemyControllerA, EnemyControllerB or EnemyControllerC because each enemy controller is slightly different for each enemy.

Comment: show us some code :)

Comment: "these cannot be input into the states" - why not? What error do you get? You should be able to pass in any derived class of `EnemyController`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are what you are refering to as the question is not very clear.
In case its not I recommend that you share a more complete attempt of what you are trying to achieve to narrow down your problem.

What I sense you might be after, is that the type of an Interface implementation can be a holder type for the children. That applies to classes that implement from interfaces, or classes that inherit from other classes. Find below the console app code examples for interface implementation and class inheritance of what I mean.

Interface:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public interface IMethodsToImplement
    {
        void method1();
        void method2();
    }

    public class InterfaceImplementer : IMethodsToImplement
    {
        public InterfaceImplementer() {

        }

        public void method1()
        {
            // whatever
        }

        public void method2()
        {
            // whatever
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<IMethodsToImplement> holderList = new List<IMethodsToImplement>() {
                new InterfaceImplementer(), new InterfaceImplementer() 
            };

            Console.WriteLine($"InterfaceImplementer count: {holderList.Count}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Inheriting from another class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class A { 
    
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public B() {

        }

        public void method1()
        {
            // whatever
        }

        public void method2()
        {
            // whatever
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<A> holderList = new List<A>() {
                new B(), new B() 
            };

            Console.WriteLine($"InterfaceImplementer count: {holderList.Count}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases the output obtained is `InterfaceImplementer count: 2`
Note how the base type or implemented interface, serves as an identificative type for any if the children in the inheritance or the implementation chain.